# React Native and Android API Level 33

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to look through the documentation but can't find a clear answer.

What is the minimum version of React Native that will work with Android API Level 33?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the RN docs under Setting up the development environment. API Level 33 is only mentioned from version 0.71

[Setting up the development environment (Android)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/environment-setup#android-sdk)

I also read another person could only get it working from 0.71.x on this thread.

[Reddit(r/reactnative): Update level api 33 android](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/15za9nc/comment/jxki0xs/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

From the above-mentioned info I believe the answer you're looking for is at least 0.71